# BLOB field not same on Ubuntu Linux and Windows Server

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, ubuntu, windows-server-2012

Im running this query on MSSQL Server from ubuntu linux 16.04 server:

`SELECT binaryImage FROM mytable;`

Well, I have retrieved binary content of my image and using `base64_encode()` function in PHP can display image.

`"<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($binaryImage)."'/>"`

It works perfectly.

But when I run same query on same database but from Windows Server 2012 R2, the binary content is different, and can't display image.

Also, I did `var_dump()` to see which binary content is retrieving on each case and is different on Linux and Windows Server. On both im using sqlsrv_pdo for php7.

I don't know what is happening... I need to run on Windows Server 2012 R2. Maybe is encoding or something like that? Thanks.

EDIT: On the left, binary content on Linux and on the right, binary content on Windows Server. On linux it has like ~1.000.000 characters lenght and on Windows, like ~2.000.000

[image]

EDIT2: Connection info.

```
$database = [
    'ServerName' => 'localhost',
    'Database' => 'db',
    'UID' => 'user',
    'PWD' => 'pass',
    'CharacterSet' => "UTF-8"
];

$conn = new PDO(
    "sqlsrv:server={$database['ServerName']};Database={$database['Database']}",
    $database['UID'],
    $database['PWD'],
    array(
        //PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    )
);
```

Comment: And _how_ is it different?

Comment: @CBroe check edit. I think is different... because why on Linux Server can display the image without problems and on windows server with the SAME code, images can't be displayed?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like an encoding problem ... have you properly _specified_ the encoding to use for the connection in both cases?

Comment: @CBroe thanks for you answer. When you mean encoding is charset? If that, im using UTF-8 on both...

Comment: Please show the code where you specified this.

Comment: @CBroe sure, check edit!

Comment: Solved! Apparently Windows Server was fetching BLOB type field as Hexadecimal while Linux directly as binary. Needed to convert hexadecimal to binary. Anyways thanks for your time @CBroe